# React native, Side menu not coming up

Tags: react-native

I followed this tutorial https://codeburst.io/custom-drawer-using-react-navigation-80abbab489f7. And when I run on emulator, I get this error:

> Invariant Violation: The navigation prop is missing for this navigator. In 
>       react-navigation 3 you must set up your app container directly

Then I changed this code:

```
export default createDrawerNavigator({
  Home: {
    screen: Home
  },
  Settings: {
    screen: Settings
  },
}, {
  contentComponent: SideMenu,
  drawerWidth: 300
});
```

to

```
const Nav = createDrawerNavigator({
  Home: {
    screen: Home
  },
  Settings: {
    screen: Settings
  },
}, {
  contentComponent: SideMenu,
  drawerWidth: 300
});
const Routes = createAppContainer(Nav);
export default Routes;
```

Then the app started working but when I click on

```
<Button onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('DrawerOpen')} title="Settings"/>
```

Nothing happens(No error as well). I'm confused

Update
If i use

```
<Button onPress={() => this.props.navigation.openDrawer()} title="Settings"/>
```

I get

> undefined is not a function (evaluating '_this.props.navigation.openDrawer()')
>   onPress
>       C:\react\cash\src\Home.js:9:8
>   touchableHandlePress
>       C:\react\cash\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Components\Touchable\TouchableNativeFeedback.android.js:196:11
>   _performSideEffectsForTransition
>       C:\react\cash\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Components\Touchable\Touchable.js:316:23
>   _receiveSignal
>       C:\react\cash\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Components\Touchable\Touchable.js:723:34
>   touchableHandleResponderRelease
>       C:\react\cash\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Components\Touchable\Touchable.js:452:17
>   invokeGuardedCallbackImpl
>       C:\react\cash\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\oss\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:99
>   invokeGuardedCallback
>       C:\react\cash\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\oss\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:343:16
>   invokeGuardedCallbackAndCatchFirstError
>       C:\react\cash\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\oss\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:346:6
>   executeDispatch
>       C:\react\cash\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\oss\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:724:32
>   executeDispatchesInOrderexecuteDispatchesAndRelease
>       C:\react\cash\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\oss\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:892
>   executeDispatchesAndReleaseTopLevelforEachAccumulated
>       C:\react\cash\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\oss\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:884:14
>   runEventsInBatch
>       C:\react\cash\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\oss\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:1066:15
>   runExtractedEventsInBatch
>       C:\react\cash\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\oss\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:1078
>   
>       C:\react\cash\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\oss\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:2726:1
>   batchedUpdates$1
>       C:\react\cash\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\oss\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:17302:5
>   batchedUpdates
>       C:\react\cash\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\oss\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:2622:6
>   _receiveRootNodeIDEvent
>       C:\react\cash\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\oss\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:2725:2
>   receiveTouches
>       C:\react\cash\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\oss\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:2788:21
>   __callFunction__guardcallFunctionReturnFlushedQueue

Answer (score 0):

The tutorial you followed might be outdated, and is probably using the 2.x version of React-navigation.

They changed the way to open a drawer to:

```
this.props.navigation.openDrawer()
```

In [this part of the doc](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/navigation-prop.html#navigator-dependent-functions), you can find what you want.